# How are migration tools like wingmandata and SfxOrgData able to set ID values?

Tags: migration, id

How do third party migration tools work? I am finding it impossible to set the ID on a custom object or a standard object when I create a new record.

So how are all these tools doing it? Is there some salesforce documentation out there that describes this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are not. Salesforce generates a unique ID for every new record, with the sole exception of records copied during a sandbox refresh. What these tools do is that they keep track of the old ID compared to the new ID, then they translate those values when loading records into the new organization.